# Drawing polygons using random points?

Tags: c++, math, calculus

I am trying to generate a set of points that I will connect to make polygon. The data has to be generated in a systematic way.

I am trying to generate the point set by randomly deriving radial coordinate `r` and evenly incrementing angular coordinate `theta` such that all the points are linked orderly without crossing with each other. I followed the correct formulas and I increment the angle but the data comes out negative because of `sin` and `cos`. I wanted to know if I'm doing this correctly.

```
struct Point2D {
    int x;
    int y;
};

Point2D poly[10];
int N = 80;

int x = (rand() % N + 1) * 5;
int y = (rand() % N + 1) * 5;
int r = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
int theta = int(atan ((float)y/(float)x) * 180 / PI);

cout << "x " << x << " y " << y << " r " << r << " theta " << theta << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    Point2D p;
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;
    poly[i] = p;

    theta += 20;
    x = r * sin(theta);
    y = r * cos(theta);

    cout << "x " << x << " y " << y << endl;

}
```

Comment: `sin` and `cos` require radians as a double. You are giving it degrees as an int.

Comment: I tried but its still negative

Comment: You are using the (integer truncated) radius based on the random point, and drawing a circle centred on (0, 0) so of course you will have negative values.

Comment: I suggest you to study [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle)

Answer (score 1):

`sin` and `cos` return points on a unit circle centered around `(0, 0)`, as paddy pointed out.  To have no negative values in the points on your own polygon, you'll need to shift the origin of that circle.  You're already changing its size, with `r * sin(theta)`; you can accomplish a minimum translation with:

```
x = r * cos(theta) + r;
y = r * cos(theta) + r;
```

When I make this change to your program, I don't get negative values anymore.

Having said that, I suspect that you're not incrementing `theta` the way you intend.  If you're trying to divide the circle into 10 equal angles, then `theta` should be a `float` or `double` and incremented like this:

```
theta += (2 * M_PI / 10);
```

`theta` is in radians, so `2 * M_PI` is once around the unit circle.